# Prove $f(x,y)$ is continuous or not continuous.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, continuity

Let
$$f(x,y)= \begin{cases}\dfrac{xy^3}{x^3+y^6}& \text{if } x^3+y^6\not =0\\ \\ 0&\text{if } x^3+y^6=0
\end{cases}
$$

Is $f$ continuous?

If $x=y^2$ then we have:

$$\lim_{y\rightarrow 0}\frac{y^2y^3}{y^6+y^6}=\lim_{y\rightarrow 0}\frac{y^5}{2y^6}=\frac{1}{2}\lim_{y\rightarrow0} \frac{1}{y}$$
And that limit doesn't exist. Then $f$ is not continuous. I'm not sure of the process, can someone review my proof?

Comment: Looks good to me

Comment: I think you have done it right.

Comment: Right on the money. +1

Comment: looks correct, nicely done!

Comment: Wouldn't be better to say that the limit is different from the value of the function instead of saying that it does not exist (it is $\infty$, but the limit exists)? For the rest the method is clearly correct.

Comment: It is correct. The way I look at it is, suppose there is some function $p$ ($p(t) = (t^2,t)$ in this case) such that $\lim_{t \to 0} p(t) =(0,0)$. If $f$ was continuous, then the limit $\lim_{t \to 0} f(p(t) )$ would be $0$. Since this is not the case, $f$ cannot be continuous.

Comment: @chak No, the limit doesn't exist, even in the generalized sense of the word, since the one sided limits are different. They are $\;\pm\infty\;$ , depending on whether $\;y\;$ tends to zero from the right or from the left.

Comment: Thanks guys for the answers!

Comment: @DonAntonio, yes obviously, my bad, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you could consider

$$f\left(|t|,\sqrt{|t|}\right) = \frac{|t|^{5/2}}{|t|^3+|t|^3} =  \frac{t^5}{2t^6} = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{|t|}} \to \infty$$
Clearly $$\lim_{t\to0}f(t^2,t)\neq 0$$

Then $f$ is not continuous. 
or $$f(t^2,|t|)  =  \frac{|t|^5}{2t^6} = \frac{1}{2|t|}$$